# Which design pattern to follow to make code structured

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have created  a class called "DownloadManagerWrapper and it will call be called based on run time argument. can i follow any design pattern for the below code to make it clean and structured. which design pattern i can go for if its possible? need your advise and sample design pattern code and simple explanation if its possible because i'm new to design pattern.

```
public class DownloadManagerWrapper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String downloadId = args[0];
    String bankId =args[1];
    String serviceId =args[2];
    readInterfaceConfig(serviceId,bankId,downloadId);
    }

    public static void readInterfaceConfig(String intfCode,String bankId,String downloadId) {

    Connection conn = CRMConnection.getConnection();

    String statusOfDownload;
    DownloadManager dwlManager = new DownloadManager();

    ResultSet rs=null;

    if(downloadId.equals("A"))
    {
    if(intfCode.equals("-1")) //all download
    {
        String query = "select INTF_CODE from CRMUSER.TABLE1 where bank_id ="+"'"+bankId+"'"+"order by INTF_CODE";
        System.out.println("query>"+query);
        try
        {
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                while(rs.next())
             {
                    String intfCodeFromDB = rs.getString("INTF_CODE");
                    statusOfDownload = new DownloadManager().downloadDataFromCore(intfCodeFromDB,bankId,downloadId);
             }
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
    else  //specific download
    {
          statusOfDownload = dwlManager.downloadDataFromCore(intfCode,bankId,downloadId);
    }
    }
    else if(downloadId.equals("I"))
    {
           if(intfCode.equals("-1")) //all download
        {
            String query = "select INTF_CODE from CRMUSER.TABLE1 where bank_id ="+"'"+bankId+"'"+"order by INTF_CODE";
            System.out.println("query>"+query);
            try
            {
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                    while(rs.next())
                 {
                        String intfCodeFromDB = rs.getString("INTF_CODE");
                        statusOfDownload = new DownloadManager().downloadDataFromCore(intfCodeFromDB,bankId,downloadId);
                 }
            }
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        }
        else  //specific download
        {
              statusOfDownload = dwlManager.downloadDataFromCore(intfCode,bankId,downloadId);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What a nice place for an SQL injection! By the way, read Clean Code, that is way more than what I could ever advise...

Comment: how to avoid sql injection in my query? thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pointers :

- Accessing DB should be through a [Data Access Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) (DAO)
  Pattern
- If you have a lot of if-statements you should take a look at the
  [Strategy Pattern](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Replace_conditional_logic_with_strategy_pattern).

Comment: i m aware of DAO pattern. I can put all of my database related code in DAO layer. is there any other pattern to follow?

Comment: yes i m exploring strategy pattern. will come back to this forum in sometime.

Comment: i accept this answer as we can use strategy pattern if there is multiple if else condition

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously, the Strategy pattern might be a good way to go. I've noticed your class only has one method. This could be a good opportunity to implement the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

The command pattern allows you to separate functionality from a class that requires it. So if you find yourself running this function a lot, this can really help with avoiding undesirable code.

Comment: yes i m exploring command pattern as well. will come back to this forum in sometime.